# Console output gets lost upon starting application as child process in C#

Tags: c#, linux, bash, docker

I'm having issues with a process started in C# not outputting to console despite it's output being redirected.

I'm running a console application inside a unityci docker container which allows me to start unity in batch mode and is supposed to output something to console.

If I use bash to start unity using `unity-editor -projectPath myProject -executeMethod myMethod -logFile -` I get all the output displayed in console as expected.

If I use C# to start a bash process using the same arguments, I get no output.

Here's the code I'm using to start a new process:

```
void StartProcess()
{
    string argsString = "-projectPath myPath -executeMethod myMethod -logFile -";
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(argsString)
    {
        FileName = "/bin/bash",
        Arguments = $"-c unity-editor \"{argsString}\"",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = false, 
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    };

    using Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;            
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    proc.WaitForExit();
}

void OnOutputDataReceived(object obj, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Data.StartsWith("[")
        Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
}
```

The `unity-editor` command is part of the unityci docker container I'm using. It does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /usr/bin/unity-editor.d ] ; then
  for i in /usr/bin/unity-editor.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
fi

xvfb-run -ae /dev/stdout "$UNITY_PATH/Editor/Unity" -batchmode "$@"
```

So in the end I have a console application that runs an executable that starts another application, and the console output gets lost somewhere in between.
Can someone explain where the output is going and how to get it to display in console?

Comment: The following may be helpful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents

Comment: You should also redirect StandardError.

Comment: I did try redirecting both at first. Turns out it wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was how I was starting the process.
Instead of starting a instance of bash to run a script like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", $"-c unity-editor \"{argsString}\"");
```

I should have just started the script as a process directly:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("unity-editor", argsString);
```

I was under the impression that you can't start bash scripts as processes directly as that would throw a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Exec format error` exception, but having `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script allows them to be run without issue.